# Create a grid for more than one country in R

Tags: raster, r, grids-graticules, sp, gstat

Some time ago I posted my own answer to create a grid inside a country to be used in kriging interpolation:

[0........0.kriging error messages, grid file problem ? (automap, gstat)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375476/0-0-kriging-error-messages-grid-file-problem-automap-gstat)

This grid was for South Africa.
Now I have data point for Lesotho (the hole inside SA), but cant get around it, to work with both together. I need a joint grid for kriging in gstat.

I used makegrid in sp:

```
SA0 <- raster::getData("GADM", country = "South Africa", level = 0)
plot(SA0)
SA0grd <- makegrid(SA0, n = 2000)
colnames(SALgrd) <- c('Longitude','Latitude')

SA0grd_pts <- SpatialPoints(coords = SALgrd, 
                    proj4string=CRS(proj4string(SA0)))



SALgrd_pts_in <- SALgrd_pts[SAL0, ]

plot(SALgrd_pts_in)
```

[image]

I tried this , did not worK

```
SAL0 <- raster::getData("GADM", country = c("South Africa", "Lesotho"), level = 0)
```

How can I create a grid for SA and Lesotho together?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you cannot pass multiple `country` arguments to `raster::getData()`, but you could simply merge two individual datasets using `rbind()`:

```r
library(sp)
library(raster)

SA0 <- raster::getData("GADM", country = "South Africa", level = 0)
les <- raster::getData("GADM", country = "Lesotho", level = 0)

sa_full <- rbind(SA0, les)

SA0grd <- sp::makegrid(sa_full, n = 2000)
colnames(SA0grd) <- c('Longitude','Latitude')

SA0grd_pts <- sp::SpatialPoints(coords = SA0grd, 
                                proj4string=CRS(proj4string(sa_full)))

SA0grd_pts_in <- SA0grd_pts[sa_full, ]

plot(SA0grd_pts_in)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you vey much for your respons.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help, I can get the grid.

Comment: However I have a problem down the line. I need to convert this to a spatial pixel df to be used in variogtam, kriging, but then the resulting file has the hole of Lesotho in the middle again. crs(SA0grd_pts_in) <- NA
SAgNA <- SA0g_pts_in  # I change the name to remember I changed the CRS
plot(SAgNA)  # this plot has Lesotho hole   SAgNA_px <- as(SAgNA, "SpatialPixels") 
class(SAgNA_px)
plot(SAgNA_px)

Comment: k1_kr = autoKrige(percent~1,SALk1b,SAgNA_px )
plot(k1_kr)

Comment: plot(k1_kr) # show a hole for Lesotho.

Comment: @MariaEugeniaD'Amato: You're welcome! I'd suggest to create a new question if your initial issue was resolved and you're facing a subsequent problem now.